# Find the number of permutations of order 2 in symmetric group $S_5$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, permutations, symmetric-groups

Find the number of permutations of order 2 in symmetric group $S_5$. Also find the number of permutations of order 2 in $A_5$

How to find the number? I can say that $(1 2)$, $(1 3)$, etc are $^5C_2$ elements of order 2. Is this right? what are others?

Comment: You also have permutations of the form $(ab)(cd)$. To make sure you get all order $2$, think about which cycle decompositions are order $2$.

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Why (ab)(cd) etc have order 2. Please elaborate

Comment: Provided that $a$, $b$, $c$ and $d$ pairwise distinct, $(ab)(cd)$ is indeed of order $2$. To see this, recall that $((ab)(cd))^2=(ab)(cd)(ab)(cd)$. Then you can use the fact that disjoint cycles commute.

Comment: Also, be careful of double counting: $(12)(34)=(34)(12)$.

Comment: @Scientifica Thanks for the idea. Then what will happen .in order to find the number of permutations of order 2 in symmetric group $S_6$ for double/triple transpositions?  $(12)(34)$ (its number will be ^6C_2\times 6) etc and $(12)(34)(56)$ (one such case will occur)? what will be the desired number? Is it $^6C_2+^6C_2\times 6+1$

Comment: For the part "find the number of permutations of order 2 in $A_5$" is the answer be $\frac{^5C_2}{2}\times 3=15$? Only counting the  double transpositions?

Comment: @user1942348 No, your $S_6$ numbers are not quite right. Eg $(12)(34)(56) \ne (13)(24)(56)$. For two transpositions, why $\times 6$? Yes, the second transposition must be chosen from the four remaining numbers, but that double counts every pair.

Comment: As almagest said, $C^6_2\times 6=C^6_2\times C^4_2$ is not the right answer for the number of double transpositions because you're double counting each such permutation. For example, you're counting both $(12)(34)$ and $(34)(12)$, yet they're equal. You should divide by $2$. For the number of triple transpositions, as almagest pointed out, $(12)(34)(56)\neq (13)(24)(56)$. You can count the number of tripple transpositions just as you did for double transpositions. But pay attention to not count things $3!$ times: $(12)(34)(56)=(12)(56)(34)=(56)(12)(34)=...$.

Comment: For the permutations of order $2$ in $A_5$, indeed the only such permutations are the double transpositions. Your computation $15=\frac{1}{2}\times C^5_2\times C^3_2$ is correct.